# \text{ something } gives error when placed inside '$$ $$' or '$ $'

Tags: math-mode, text

Even when I remove the double \quad and give space between the curly brackets like \text{ and }, I get the undefined control sequence error. I have seen examples of people using it but when I try it it does not work. Is there a specific package that I need to install?
[image: $ \text{ error } $]

[image: $$ \text{ error } $$]

Comment: Don't use `$$` for displayed maths in LaTeX. Instead use `\[` and `\]` or `\begin{equation}` and `\end{equation}`. Did you load the `amsmath` package? You should do if you want to typeset maths. For `\text` you at least need to load `amstext` (part of `amsmath`).

Comment: Also, please don't show screenshots of errors, but the part of the log-file that includes the error. LaTeX errors are a lot more meaningful if you can read the logs than some screenshot showing "Undefined control sequence" (as that doesn't show which control sequence is undefined, the log does).

Comment: Please write a minimal working example. See [link](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/250119) for more details what it means.

Comment: @Skillmon Okay, I didnt even think of opening the .log file, thanks for that you were really helpful!